option legalpaper for documentclass exam not working -- please help
I am trying to create a multiple choice exam on US Legal paper. I am using TeXShop on a MacBook Air M2 running MacOS 14.4.1. I've just installed TeXLive 2024. Here is part of the console log:
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/exam/exam.cls
Document Class: exam 2023/07/09 Version 2.704 by Philip Hirschhorn
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class

The exam documentclass works as expected with the default letter paper size (no option to documentclass, but when I add option legalpaper, it no longer works reliably.
Here is my source file (taken from the manual at https://math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/examdoc.pdf):
\documentclass[answers,12pt]{exam}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheadrule
\firstpagefootrule 
\firstpageheader{Math 115}{Final Exam}{July 4, 1776}
\runningheader{Math 115}
{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
{July 4, 1776}
\firstpagefooter{Math 115}{Final Exam}{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
\runningfooter{Math 115}{Final Exam}{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
\runningheadrule 
\runningfootrule 
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

EXAM

\begin{questions}

\question My question with multiple choices.

\begin{choices}
   \choice The first choice.
   \choice The second choice.
   \choice The third choice.
   \choice The fourth choice.
   \CorrectChoice The fifth choice.
\end{choices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}

which produces this output: 
When I add only the legalpaper option to my source file (from page 102 of exam.cls documentation):
\documentclass[legalpaper,answers,12pt]{exam}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheadrule
\firstpagefootrule 
\firstpageheader{Math 115}{Final Exam}{July 4, 1776}
\runningheader{Math 115}
{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
{July 4, 1776}
\firstpagefooter{Math 115}{Final Exam}{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
\runningfooter{Math 115}{Final Exam}{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
\runningheadrule 
\runningfootrule 
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

EXAM

\begin{questions}

\question My question with multiple choices.

\begin{choices}
   \choice The first choice.
   \choice The second choice.
   \choice The third choice.
   \choice The fourth choice.
   \CorrectChoice The fifth choice.
\end{choices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}

I get the following output (extra space above the header and no footer):


It is definitely a bug, but you can fix it with \setlength\pdfpageheight{\paperheight}.

The class doesn't set up the pdf size so if your site default is A4 the page size options don't really work and it's not clear they work even if your site default is us letter (I didn't trace its settings).
You could report that to the package maintainers but the easiest fix (for them and you) is to load geometry to fix things up.
You could if you want adjust other things using the geometry options, for example increase \textheight a bit if you wish,
The pdfinfo utility reports
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)


\documentclass[
letterpaper
,answers,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{geometry}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheadrule
\firstpagefootrule 
\firstpageheader{Math 115}{Final Exam}{July 4, 1776}
\runningheader{Math 115}
{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
{July 4, 1776}
\firstpagefooter{Math 115}{Final Exam}{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
\runningfooter{Math 115}{Final Exam}{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
\runningheadrule 
\runningfootrule 
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

EXAM

\begin{questions}

\question My question with multiple choices.

\begin{choices}
   \choice The first choice.
   \choice The second choice.
   \choice The third choice.
   \choice The fourth choice.
   \CorrectChoice The fifth choice.
\end{choices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}


Thanks! That did the trick. I have letter as my default paper size. I will suggest a mention of the geometry package in the exam.cls documentation to its maintainers.
